# Prove that there exists a unique real number $x$ between $0$ and $1$ such that $x ^{3} + x^2 − 1 = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

I think I'm on the right track with constructing this proof. Please let me know.

Claim: Prove that there exists a unique real number $x$ between $0$ and $1$ such that
$x^{3}+x^{2} -1=0$

Using the intermediate value theorem we get 
$$r^{3}+r^{2}-1=c^{3}+c^{2}-1$$
......
$$r^{3}+r^{2}-c^{3}-c^{2}=0$$

Factoring gives us

$$(r-c)[(r^{2}+rc+c^{2})+(r+c)]=0$$
I'm lost now. How do I prove that there exists a number between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Sorry...what does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: The title was a different question from earlier. Sorry I'm fixing now.

Comment: Drop the intermediate value theorem. Check Derivative and find areas of monotonicity.

Comment: I've edited the question to make the polynomial in the title match the one in the body. Please make sure it's correct. Also, please check tag descriptions before using them.

Comment: T. it is correct, Thank you. Sorry I've screwed this question all the way up when I posted it

Comment: Whar are the values of $f(0)$ and $f(1)$?. Have you heard of the intermediate value theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Existence follows from the intermediate value theorem, and uniqueness from the fact that the derivative has constant sign on this interval. But let's prove that the zero is actually unique on the entire real line.

---

Suppose the polynomial $p$ has real zeros at $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Take $\beta$ to be the largest zero, which happens to be near $0.6$. You can check this using the intermediate value theorem and looking at the derivative.

By the mean value theorem, there exists a number $c$ between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for which

$$p'(c) = \frac{p(\alpha) - p(\beta)}{\alpha - \beta} = 0$$

That is, $3c^2 + 2c = 0$. Thus either $c = 0$ or $c = -2/3$.

Now $p(-2/3) < 0$ and $p'(x) > 0$ for $x < -2/3$, so there are no zeros in this domain. Hence, $\alpha$ must lie between $0$ and $-2/3$.

Now argue this can't happen directly: Perhaps start with the fact that $|x^3 + x^2| < 1$ on $(-2/3, 0)$.

Finally, conclude that $\beta$ is unique.

Comment: Thanks T. I tried to upvote you but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 1):

You just need the intermediate value theorem and monotonicity. Put $p(x) = x^3 + x^2 - 1$. Since $p(0) = -1$ and $p(1)= 1$, the intermediate value theorem says that there is at least one value $r \in (0,1)$ such that $p(r) = 0$.

Consider $p'(x) = 3x^2 + 2x > 0$ for $x \in (0,1]$. Hence $p$ is increasing. Thus for any $s < r < t$ we have $p(s) < 0 < p(t)$. This shows that there is no other point in $(0,1]$ where $p$ is zero.

EDIT: Alternatively, your approach works: if $p(r) = p(c) = 0$, as you stated, we have $$(r-c) (r^2+rc+c^2+r+c) = 0.$$ Thus $r - c = 0$ or $r^2+rc+c^2+r+c = 0$. In the latter case, we would have $r= 0, c = 0$ which doesn't work, since $p(0) \neq 0$, so instead we must have $r- c = 0$ which gives $r=c$. Thus the root is unique.

Comment: Thank you. So in my proof just show that I plugged in 0, and 1(since they were given)? Would this be a direct proof?

Comment: Yes. This is a direct proof.

Answer (score 0):

You want an $x$ in $(0, 1)$ such that $x^2 + x = 1/x$. Note that as $x$ goes to zero $x^2 + x < 1/x,$ and as $x$ goes to one $x^2 + x > 1/x$. Since both curves are continuous they must intersect at least once on $(0, 1),$ and since $x^2 + x$ is increasing on that interval whereas $1/x$ is decreasing they intersect exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

You might rewrite the factor $(r^2+rc+c^2+r+c)$ as
$$r^2+rc+c^2+r+c = \underbrace{(r-c)^2}_{\ge0}+\underbrace{3rc}_{\ge0}+\underbrace r_{\ge0}+\underbrace c_{\ge0}\ge0 $$
with equality only if $r=c=0$.